# Extending a view which overrides onMeasure()

Tags: android, view, onmeasure

I have a view `view1` which extends FrameLayout and overrides onMeasure() like this, so that it is rendered as a square:

```
  @Override
  protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
  }
```

Now I want to create another view `view2` which extends `view1`, but now I want `view2` to have a height equal to the parent, and hence to cover the full screen. As of now, I get it as a square too.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In view 1:

```
private boolean measureAsSquare = true;

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    if (measureAsSquare) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    }
    else {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}

public void setMeasureAsSquare(boolean b) {
    measureAsSquare = b;
}
```

In View2 constructor that subclasses view 1:

```
public View2(Context c) {
    setMeasureAsSquare(false);
}
```

Then you can use normal layout weight and height for view 2 to assign its preferred size.

Comment: You made my day! I was overthinking this. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since the onMeasure for **Square** was already overridden where it disregards the height passed to it, as per your code:

```
@Override
  protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
  }
```

One way to do what you want -- *view2 which extends view1, but now I want view2 to have a height equal to the parent, and hence to cover the full screen* -- is to also override **onMeasure** of view2 calling on setDimension like this...

```
public class Square2 extends Square {

    public Square2(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

Here is a sample after I tried it out. (For code in Square View, I just copied your code in onMeasure).

Using Square:
[image]

For Squre2:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: It seems for you to be able to provide the height and not just simple to have it equal to the parent, you just have to change -- 
setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT); -- to 
setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);